# Perl php script auto install?

Tags: php, perl

I was think of learning Perl cause I hear around town its good for system admin things. Would it be possible to use it to automatically install a php script? I need to install a custom script  on a few different server and wanted to know how I could make something in Perl to do it (like move scripts over to directory and stuff)?

Comment: Why not go with python instead? It's more civilized.

Comment: If by civilized, you mean ..., oh never mind. I won't go there.

Comment: PHP as good af perl in system admin things. Why not to use php if you (supposedly) already know it?

Comment: PHP is more for web development, not for scripting Debian system stuff.. at least that is how it feels. And I may use python instead since I no more about that than Perl.

Comment: @jpartogi - Jedi all got killed, remember? Don't bring a civilized weapon to a gun fight an all that :) 
And that comment was kinda flamey, don'tchathink?

Comment: you're just wrong about PHP. Surprizingly, it can copy a file. And even create a directory! Go figure

Comment: ☺ I've never heard of anyone choosing between two programming languages on the basis of which one was more civilized.

Comment: I agree that learning Perl or Python just to write a script that installs a PHP script seems ... if civilization has anything to do with it, *decadent* is the term that comes to mind.  Use PHP already!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Perl can easily do that (and a lot more).

You can use `File::Copy` module to move/copy files around, or if you need to FTP them to different server, `Net::FTP` module.

Answer (score 1):

i dont really know very bien perl scripts but i think these example scripts for irc installs and configures could help you! :)
http://variant.googlecode.com/files/perl.txt
http://variant.googlecode.com/files/allnet.pl

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware of, in terms of sysadmin scripts PHP can do what ever Perl can do.